# A little trouble with passive voice

Tags: syntactic-analysis, passive-voice

I've recently came across some sentence structures that confused me a bit.

Consider these two examples:

> 1. After the Crisis was ended, he was promoted.
> 2. After the Crisis ended, he was promoted.

Both sentences sound fine to me, but I can't tell if the second sentence is wrong. Considering that the verb-to-be is missing, I'd say it's grammatically incorrect, but it sounds so fine to me.

Is my gut feeling wrong?

Comment: The auxiliary *was* in the first sentence puts the verb in passive voice, emphasizing that something or someone ended the crisis. The second sentence uses *end* as a stative, saying merely that the crisis was over. I don't know why *Crisis* is capitalized, but both sentences are grammatical.

Comment: Since one criticism of passive voice is that it doesn't identify the party responsible for an action but instead merely reports the occurrence of the action, it is somewhat telling that you can remove both passives from your original sentence and still be none the wiser about who or what ended the war and who or what granted the promotion: "After the crisis ended, he received a promotion."

Comment: @deadrat Ah yes, that makes sense. While Crisis was capitalized because it was talking about a specific crisis in the original text, nothing special about it.

Comment: "After the Crisis **had** ended, he was promoted."

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with the second sentence. It simply states the fact that after the crisis ended, he was promoted. Compare: "After the rain stopped, the sun came out."

The first sentence is potentially more problematic in that it refers indirectly to the party that did the ending. For example: "After the crisis was ended *by the counterrevolutionaries*, he was promoted."

The first sentence could also read, "After the crisis **had been ended** *by the counterrevolutionaries*, he was promoted." This sentence links the promotion more immediately to the ending of the crisis. It all comes down to the context and what exactly you are trying to say.